# FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for GridFragment{...} not updated inline; expected state 1 found 0

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a simple Activity and Retained Fragment, just as [Alex Lockwood blog post example](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html).

My activity goes like this inside `onCreate()`:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    retainedFragment = (GridFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(RETAINED_FRAGMENT_TAG);

    // If the Fragment is non-null, then it is currently being
    // retained across a configuration change.
    if (retainedFragment == null) {
        retainedFragment = new GridFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(retainedFragment, RETAINED_FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
    }else{
        list = retainedFragment.getList();
        System.out.println(list.size());//OUTPUT 12
    }
```

And my `Fragments`' `onAttach()` is :

```
 @Override
public void onAttach(Context activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mCallbacks = (TaskCallbacks) activity;
    System.out.println("here"); //OUTPUT here
}
```

Now, on every screen rotation I've got very strange output:

> I/System.out: here
>
> W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for
>   GridFragment{95fc9db #0 retained_tag} not updated inline; expected
>   state 1 found 0
>
> I/System.out: 12

Where is that strange warning comes from right between my inputs? How to deal with it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: +1 Same for me. Did you find any solution? The app is getting slow after about 20 rotation changes, until I close and reopen it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This message doesn't matter and the extra log was removed in Support Library v24.0.0
This is official developer [answer](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202037#c14):

> For the curious, FragmentManager.moveToState now updates the new
>   fragment state as it goes rather than at the end after all of the
>   state change phases have completed. This fixed several interesting
>   bugs around using the child fragment manager and
>   executePendingTransactions from within one of the parent fragment's
>   lifecycle callbacks.
>
> One of the state transitions as we're bringing a fragment up is a
>   no-op that wasn't getting the state updated inline, and the log you're
>   seeing is announcing that we did it at the end instead, exactly as we
>   would have prior to 23.2.

Answer (score 2):

I found the same behavior several days ago when moving from the support library appcompat-v7 23.1.1 to 23.4.0.

It seems the error is in the newer support library. With 23.1.1 I was not having the error. After investigating for a while, I can see the error was introduced in 23.2.0.

If you can move back to 23.1.1 the warning won't be appearing.

A similar issue is mentioned here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202037

But it seems it was only investigated and related with tabs. The issue seems marked as resolved for a future version. But I don't know if this is going to solve our use case.

Hope this helps with the problem.